# Update StoredProcedure executes but DB not updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, data-binding, devexpress

I've searched around for a while and tried all the different solutions but I can't seem to get the database updated.

I've executed the stored procedure on its own through SSMS and it works fine.

Here's my asp settings:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" UpdateCommand="spProofStamp" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="sID" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Button:

```
<dx:LayoutItem Caption="">
    <LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
        <dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer ID="LayoutItemNestedControlContainer1" runat="server">
            <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxFormLayout2_E2" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" Text="Validate" AutoPostBack="false">
                <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s,e){validate();}" />

            </dx:ASPxButton>
        </dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
    </LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
</dx:LayoutItem>
```

My code behind (I've tried databind and update separately as well).

I've also traced through the values and they're all there, how can I tell if the Update/DataBind works or not? Other Databinds within my code are working fine:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource5.UpdateCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataSource5.UpdateCommand = "spProofStamp";
    SqlDataSource5.UpdateParameters["sID"].DefaultValue = selectedValue;
    SqlDataSource5.UpdateParameters["UserID"].DefaultValue = login.ToUpper();
    SqlDataSource5.Update();
    SqlDataSource5.DataBind();
}
```

StoredProcedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spProofStamp]
@UserID nvarchar(15),
@sID nvarchar(15)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
UPDATE [dbo].[ORDER]

SET [USERID] = @UserID,
    [DATE] = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

WHERE ID = @sID
```

Comment: Is there any chance you're using a transaction and not committing the same?

Comment: I'm not using a transaction.. I've executed the stored procedure on its own and it works fine.

Comment: When I see this kind of problems (with a not clear error in code) I always think that something is wrong in the connection string. Are you sure that you are looking at the correct database? If you have listed its file between your project files always check the value of Copy To Output Directory

Comment: The connection string has to be correct because it's the same connection string I use to pull data. All of the stored procedures are in the same stored procedure folder.. the spellings double checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to recommend you to change your method from sqldatasource to code behind, as it makes your code more clear and it is more effective.

You may use the next method:

```
protected void UpdateDB(string user_id, string sid){
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(your_connection_string);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spProofStamp", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@USERID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = user_id;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sid;

    try{
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        //process your exception
    }
    finally{
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri); //refresh this page
    }
}
```

And call your method:

```
UpdateDB(login.ToUpper(), selectedValue);
```

Comment: You've helped immensely, thank you so much. With your suggestion and this site, it got me through: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2000/ (since I'm using sql server 2000)